# the diffrence between angular.foreach and "for"

Tags: angularjs

I tried the Todo Example in Angular home page (No.2) and modified a little code which cause a wired problem. 
   When I add two Todo, the dispaly is ok which is displayed as “4 of 4 remain [archive]”,then I select 2 Todo item and click "acrhive". The result should be “2 of 2 remain [archive]", but acctually the display is “2 of 4 remain [archive]". 
   Then I replace ”for“ loop wiht "angular.forEach" function,  the result is correct.
   So anyone can explain what is the diffrence when I use between "for loop" and "angular.forEach"？ 
The coding is shown as belowing:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app ng-controller="ToDo">
<span>{{remains()}} of {{total}} remain</span><span>[<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="archive()">archive</a>]</span>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.checked">{{todo.item}}
        </input>
    </li>
    <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="toDoitem" placeholder="add Todo List here"></input>
    <span><input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add"></input></span>
    </form>
</ul>
<script>
var ToDo = function ($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [
        {item:"Discuss with my team",checked:false},
        {item:"Mail to Jack",checked:false}
    ];

    $scope.total = $scope.todos.length;
    $scope.remains = function() {
        var count =0;
        for (var i=0;i<$scope.todos.length;i++) {
            count += $scope.todos[i].checked?0:1
        };
        return count;
    };
    $scope.action= function($index) {
        $scope.todos[$index].checked=!todos[$index].checked
        $scope.remain += todos[$index].checked?-1:1;
    };
    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.total ++;
        $scope.todos.push({item:$scope.toDoitem,checked:false});
        $scope.toDoitem = '';
    }; 
    $scope.archive = function() {
        var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
        $scope.todos = [];

        for (var i=0;oldTodos.length-1;i++){
            if (!oldTodos[i].checked) {
                $scope.todos.push({item:oldTodos[i].item,checked:false});
            };
        };
/*  
        angular.forEach(oldTodos,function(todo){
            if (!todo.checked) {
                $scope.todos.push(todo);
            };
        });
*/      
        $scope.total = $scope.todos.length;
    };
};
//http://jsfiddle.net
//http://plnkr.co/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your example in Fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your example there is nothing in particular different between angular.forEach and a standard for loop.

You don't appear to be pushing the same object into $scope.todos in the forEach, does the following help:

```
angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
  if (!todo.checked) {
    $scope.todos.push({item: todo.item, checked: false});
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a look at the implementation for forEach for arrays and compare it with yours:

Angularjs forEach implementation for arrays:

```
      for (key = 0; key < obj.length; key++)
        iterator.call(context, obj[key], key);
```

And yours:

```
    for (var i=0;oldTodos.length-1;i++){
        if (!oldTodos[i].checked) {
            $scope.todos.push({item:oldTodos[i].item,checked:false});
        };
    };
```

You could try:

```
    for (var i=0; i < oldTodos.length; i++){
        if (!oldTodos[i].checked) {
            $scope.todos.push({item:oldTodos[i].item,checked:false});
        };
    };
```

Comment: Select my answer as correct if you got the answer you were looking for. :)